# C# Determine Type using Regex with Switch syntactic sugar

Tags: c#, switch-statement, syntactic-sugar

I have a string which based on a regex matching is of format_1 or format_2 etc. I use regex named groups to extract `clientId` variable.

```
var sampleName = "001-99-26Jul2023";
var sampleNameFormat1 = @"[0-9]{3}-(?<clientId>[0-9]{2})-[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}";
var sampleNameFormat2 = @"[0-9]{4}-(?<clientId>[0-9]{2})-[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}";
var sampleNameFormat3 = @"[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}";

var regexMatch = sampleName switch
{
    var _ when Regex.IsMatch(sampleName, sampleNameFormat1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) => Regex.Match(sampleName, sampleNameFormat1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase),
    var _ when Regex.IsMatch(sampleName, sampleNameFormat2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) => Regex.Match(sampleName, sampleNameFormat2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase),
    var _ when Regex.IsMatch(sampleName, sampleNameFormat3, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) => Regex.Match(sampleName, sampleNameFormat3, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase),
    _ => null,
};


var clientIdString = regexMatch.Result("${clientId}");

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientIdString)) // If check, because `sampleNameFormat3` does not have this named grouping <clientId>
{
    int clientId = ParseInteger(clientIdString);
}
```

Problems:

1. I do the regex match call twice. Is there a syntax that makes it more clean? Some way to change the switch statement? Only one Regex.Match call.
2. As you see in Format 3 there is no `<clientId>`, so the last assignment
   `var clientIdString = regexMatch.Result("${clientId}");` will result in `clientIdString = "${clientId}"`.
   So, the if check will enter and error `ParseInteger("${clientId}")`.
   The solution would be to write:
   `var clientIdString = regexMatch.Groups["clientId"].Value;` this assigns empty string and if-check does not enter. I don't know if this is the right way, so I wanted to ask you too what you consider.

Comment: `when Regex.Match(...) is Match m && m.Success =>` ? The `is Match` will always succeed because it never returns `null`, but so does the `var` pattern before it. A lot of unconditional success leading to what matters is rather pointless. The `switch` expression syntax is getting out of hand here. I'd switch (no pun intended) to using an array of `Regex` instances and looping on that until a match is found, and moving this in its own method instead of being part of something larger.

Comment: Side note: `sampleNameFormat1` and `sampleNameFormat2` can be unified by starting with `[0-9]{3,4}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch is overkill, and doesn't really add much in terms of readability or succinctness.

Just do

```
var m = Regex.Match(sampleName, sampleNameFormat1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (!m.Success)
    m = Regex.Match(sampleName, sampleNameFormat2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
if (!m.Success)
    m = Regex.Match(sampleName, sampleNameFormat3, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

if (m.Success)
{
    // all your other logic
}
```

If you add some number of cases, then I suggest looping over the calls as you and @madreflection suggest in the comments. Something like

```cs
Match match = null;
foreach (var regexFormat in regexFormats)
{
    match = Regex.Match(sampleName, regexFormat, regexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    
    if (match.Success) break;
}

if (!match.Success) return null;

// all your other logic
```

or

```cs
Match match = null;
foreach (var regexFormat in regexFormats)
{
    match = Regex.Match(sampleName, regexFormat, regexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // all your other logic
        return something...;
    }
}

return null;
```

Comment: Based in your help, managed to do something like this:
```
foreach (var regexFormat in regexFormats)
{
 match = Regex.Match(sampleName, regexFormat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 if (match.Success)
 {
  break;
 }
}
if (!match.Success)
{
 return null;
}
```